# C# clear "styles.xml" in the book excel (xlsx) using closedxml

Tags: c#, .net, excel, styles, closedxml

I have a C# program which insert values and applies styles to an Excel workbook (xlsx). I use the ClosedXML library.

I ran into the problem that after many file entries (xlsx), the style of the book does not apply.
I noticed that the file size increases over time and when I changed the file extension from .xlsx to .zip and unzipped it I noticed that the file "styles.xml" is large in size 8 - 10 MB.
I think that the reason for the file overflow "styles.xml".

How to clean using ClosedXML all previously applied styles in the book excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
foreach (var worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
    worksheet.Clear(XLClearOptions.AllFormats);
```

`AllFormats` includes conditional formats too. If you want to preserve them use `NormalFormats`, as Francois suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "clean" all the styles, i.e. set all cells' style to the default style value, you can use:

```
foreach (var cell in worksheet.CellsUsed(XLCellsUsedOptions.NormalFormats))
{
    cell.Style = XLWorkbook.DefaultStyle;
}
```

Ensure you're using the latest version of ClosedXML (v0.94.2 at the time of writing).